# CloseableHttpClient execute takes so much time

Tags: java, rest

When I make a call to the method CloseableHttpClient.execute it takes so much time to finish the first time I call it. For example, if I call an API call 10 times in a for bucle, the first call takes much more time than the rest of the call and I don't know the reason.
I would appreciate if someone can help.
Regards.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, Exception
    {
        AcanoAPICallsTest2 test = new AcanoAPICallsTest2();
        AcanoAPIHandler clientHandler = test.getClientHandler();

        if (clientHandler.getConnectCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)        {

            int statusCode = clientHandler.executeMethod(CommonSettings.GET, "/api/xxx);

            }
        }

        clientHandler.shutDownClient();
    }


public class AcanoAPIHandler extends ClientHandler
{
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final String LOCATION = "Location";
    private String location;
//    private int connectCode = HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;

    /**
     * Returns the "Location" field of the response header (if exists)
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getLocationHeaderResponse()
    {
        return location;
    }

    // default constructor
    public AcanoAPIHandler()
    {
        super();
    }

    public AcanoAPIHandler(String protocol, String host, Integer port, String username, String password) 
    {
        super(protocol, host, port, username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public int executeMethod(String type, String path, List<BasicNameValuePair>... nvps) 
    {
        int statusCode = super.executeMethod(type, path, nvps);
        this.location = null;
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.POST) || type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.PUT))
        {
            // if statusCode is 200, set the location header
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                Header[] h = this.getResponse().getAllHeaders();
                for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++)
                {
                    if (h[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(LOCATION))
                    {
                        String locationStr = h[i].getValue();
                        String[] split = locationStr.split("/");
                        if (split.length > 0)
                        {
                            this.location = split[split.length - 1];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return statusCode;

    }

}
```

ClientHandler.executeMethod

```
public int executeMethod(String type, String path, List<BasicNameValuePair>... nvps) 
{
    int statusCode = -1;
    HttpUriRequest request = createUriRequest(type, path);
    this.responseContent = null;
    this.response = null;

    try
    {
        if (nvps.length > 0)
        {
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.POST))
            {
                ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps[0], "UTF-8"));
            }
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.PUT))
            {
                ((HttpPut) request).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps[0], "UTF-8"));
            }
            else
            {
                logger.warn("Can only set entity on POST/PUT operation, ignoring nvps");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if (this.httpclient != null)
    {
        try
        {   
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            this.response = this.httpclient.execute(request);

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long res = end - start;
            System.out.println("httpclient.execute " + " seconds: "+res/1000);

            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                InputStream fis = entity.getContent();
                this.responseContent = convertStreamToString(fis);
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return SERVER_ERROR;
        }
        finally
        {
            // release connection
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.GET))
            {
                ((HttpGet) request).releaseConnection();
            }
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.POST))
            {
                ((HttpPost) request).releaseConnection();
            }
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.PUT))
            {
                ((HttpPut) request).releaseConnection();
            } 
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonSettings.DELETE))
            {                
                ((HttpDelete) request).releaseConnection();
            }

            // close the response
            try
            {
                if (this.response != null)
                {
                    this.response.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return SERVER_ERROR;
            }
        }

    }

    return statusCode;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how `this.httpclient` is initialized in `ClientHandler` class, but usually this happens when you are executing request to a host which is far away from you and uses reusable http connections (this is why the first request is noticeably slower than others).
When you open [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) connection to a host, TCP three way handshake is made. This means that you have to wait before connection is established and only after that actual HTTP request is sent. Establishing connection from Europe to somewhere in North America would take ~90ms and more. [Ping time from London to other cities](https://wondernetwork.com/pings/London) 
Using TCP connection multiple times is a good practice. Because after TCP connection is established and the first request is done you can send new requests without extra waiting time. You can read more about [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)

Seems that you are connecting to Acano servers, I don't know exactly where their Data Center(-s) is/are, cause they can have couple of them across the world, but the company is located in USA. So seems legit in case you are not very close to the Arcano's Data Center.

Comment: I run my java program in two different servers in the same location and the result is different, in one of the servers the response time is <1sg and in the other server the response time is 28 seconds. In the log I see what is the call is taking so much time: DEBUG [org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager] Connecting to /xx.202.xxx.11:443

Comment: 1sg means 1sec? Are this results consistent, like you did 10 consecutive tries (each consists of 10 requests) on each server and every time the first request on the second server was a way more slower? The first request in a row is slower in both servers or only on the second? Do the second (and other) requests on different servers differs as much as the first requests?

Comment: Which version of HttpClient library are you using?

Comment: 4.3.1 If I make only 1 call in one of my servers it takes around 28 seconds, If I make the same call (same java program) in another server it takes 1 second and I don't know why this difference.

Comment: On server 1 the first call takes 28 seconds - ok, does subsequent requests from the same 1st server longs for 1 second or for ~28sec? Each request on the 2nd server takes only 1 second and this doesn't depend from request index?

Comment: Problem fixed with 4.3.5 version. Thanks anyway!